# How to depict interaction terms in a table of regression output?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, interaction

When building a multiple regression model with categorical interacting terms, not all combinations of categorical interactions are shown in model output. This occurs because these terms drop out. Say we have the following multiple linear regression model with the from the `iris` dataset in `R`:

$y = \alpha + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \beta_3X_3 + \beta_4X_4 + \beta_5X_1X_3 + \beta_6X_1X_4 + \beta_7X_2X_3 + \beta_8X_2X_4 + \epsilon$

Where:

$y$ is `Sepal.Length`

$X_1$ is where `Species` equals versicolor

$X_2$ is where `Species` equals virginica

and $X_3$ and $X_4$ are categories of `Sepal.Width`, such that

$X_3$ is where `Sepal.Width` is between $3.0$ and $3.5$

$X_4$ is where `Sepal.Width` is greater than 3.5

This makes reference groups where `Species` equals setosa and where `Sepal.Width` is less than $3.0$. Any time when an observation with either of the reference groups occurs, that specific $\beta$ term drops from the model. Additionally, any time an observation contains either of the reference groups, the interaction term will drop out.

Often times, reference groups are depicted in model output in a publication like so (with random numbers):

```
Species            Estimate
  setosa (ref)         -
  versicolor          .66
  virginica           .75

  Sepal.Width0 (ref)   -
  Sepal.Width1        .45
  Sepal.Width2        .86

  versicolor:Sepal.Width1 1.24
  versicolor:Sepal.Width2 1.84

  virginica:Sepal.Width1 2.34
  virginica:Sepal.Width2 3.64
```

This leaves out the following combinations without parameter estimates as they drop out of the regression equation:

- `setosa:Sepal.Width0`
- `setosa:Sepal.Width1`
- `setosa:Sepal.Width2`
- `versicolor:Sepal.Width0`
- `virginica:Sepal.Width0`

**Question: How are the categorical interaction terms that drop out of the model generally depicted?** Adding all combinations of interaction terms where the terms drop to zero will generally take up too much space without adding any information. Also, following the categories with *(ref)* is technically not true, as these terms in categorical interactions are not technically *reference* groups.

Comment: It depends how you intend to present the interacted model. If you're just showing model coefficients, there's nothing wrong with showing the setosa : Sepal.Width0 effect as (ref).

Comment: @AdamO Interesting. Do you know of any tables in published literature that show interaction in that way? For reference?

Comment: @AdamO My apologies, I just realized I had an error in my question. The table I created was not correct because `setosa:Sepal.Width1` and `setosa:Sepal.Width2` would not have parameters. I replaced `setosa` in both of these with `versicolor` for clarification. In the provided example, 5 of the 9 combinations between `Species` and `Sepal.Width` should not have beta parameters, as they drop out in the regression equation. These are not truly (ref) groups? So how should they be portrayed?